# Redirection to external site on admin

Tags: wp-admin, admin-menu

I have a menu on Admin which opens a page in admin.

The issue is that when I open that menu it redirect to another site like www.abc.com, the admin menu includes DB connection and it list the product pages.

The admin is redirecting to a URL I know but I don't where that URL is defined? and why is it redirecting?

I would be grateful if any one has any idea about this issue.

Comment: Have you checked your .htaccess file, functions.php (theme) and your plugins? It's possible to be coded directly in the .htaccess file but most probably the plugin/theme which includes the menu is responsible.

Comment: @denis I have checked .htaccess and function theme file but i don't see anything which redirects.

Answer (score -3):

You have use Appearance-> Menu and use custom menu and provide link there.

Comment: @chirayu this is not custom menu, this is an admin menu, when I click on it it loads the page for few seconds then redirect to external site. The site is not defined in .htaccess file either.

Comment: You use add_menu hook for admin menu. this better solution see the wordpres reference example and use code.